# How to import custom ships into particle fleet simulation?

Tags: particle-fleet-emergence

Is there a way to import custom ships into a simulation in Particle Fleet Emergence? When I click "Simulation" I see a bunch of options, but my only ship choices are the default ones, not ships I have created in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first screen you see (random parameters, fleet selection) when you click on the Simulation button is just a mission editor, as it were. Once you click 'launch mission', you'll be taken to the regular pre-mission screen, where you can select between the default fleet and the sandbox fleet.

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to select "Sandbox fleet" when staring the game.

(I would add an screenshot but png is disabled)

The select your ship on the right in the "Custom" section

Comment: In the `simulation`, not the missions